# sparkjobserver adds a [ in front of every { and [

Tags: json, spark-jobserver

I am using sparkjobserver restful service. Everything works fine except the returned json string has an extra [] around every object and array. Each array becomes

```
[[.......]]. and each object becomes

[{.....}]
```

has anyone seen this problem before? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to return json string as result. If you return Scala object, then it is marshalled by sprays complete API